# How does the python range command work with lists?

Tags: python, list

Hey everyone i have this issue here, i really can't make out what the problem is. 
I know that range(2) gives 0 and 1 for possible i. len(R) = 2. And lists starts with 0.

```
R = [[1,1],[5,5]]
for i in range(len(R)):
    if R[i][0] == R[i][1]:     
        R.remove(R[i])
```

the error:

```
if R[i][0] == R[i][1]:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: When you **remove** from the list, its size shrinks

Comment: Oh yeah, ofcourse!

Comment: Consider using [``filter``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) for deleting items from a collection based on a simple predicate on item, in your case f.e. ``filter(lambda r: r[0] != r[1], R)``

Answer (score 2):

```
R = [[1,1],[5,5]]
R = [x for x in R if x[0] != x[1]]
```

It should be != instead of == since he wants to get the numbers that are not identical.

Answer (score -3):

In general, It's much easier to iterate over the items in the list:

```
Removal_items =[]
for I in R:
  #I is now a variable that represents the object in the list, or I = R[0]...R[n] where n = len(r) -1
  if I[0] == I[1]:
  Removal_items.append(I)

for I in Removal_items:
  R.remove(I)
```

Comment: Oh that is of course another possibility to look at it! Thanks! I will try that!

Comment: Nope, this won't work. It'll skip items after each removal.

Comment: See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list for why this does not work.

Comment: Thanks guys i see now why this indeed does not work!

Comment: Ok this won't run verbatim but the idea is there. I'll fix er up